# Access to an id in has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have 3 **models,user,store and product**. The relationship is `User has_many stores`, and `Product has_many stores`. In this case if i do current_user.stores, I get an array of stores the particular user has. But now I want to return stores with certain products where I could have access to **product_id**, which I could do
`current_user.stores.where(:product_id=>1)`, but the thing is in my case, I can't access the **product_id** , so which other way could I use to accomplish that, maybe **has_many, scope** but I don't know how. Can anybody help me please?

```
 def my_account
   #@product=Product.find(params[:id]) ,this cant find the id
   if user_signed_in?
     @my_stores=current_user.stores.where(:product_id=>@product.id)
   end
 end
```

view

```
   <% @my_stores.each do |store| %>
   <%=store.name%>
   <%end%>
```

Comment: What is the error you get when you try `current_user.stores.where(:product_id => 1)`, i.e. what prevents you from accessing Store#product_id?

Comment: `current_user.stores.where(:product_id => 1)` works but `Product.find(params[:id])` return could't find it without an id,the url doesnt have an id obviously.

Answer (score 0):

The (`store`, `product`) has a `many-to-many` relationship between them, so you might have to introduce an intermediary model as shown below:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :stores
end

class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :store_products
  has_many :products, :through => :store_products
end

class StoreProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :store
 belongs_to :product
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :store_products
  has_many :stores, :through => :store_products
end
```

Now given a user you can get the stores as follows:

```
user.stores # all stores associated with the user
```

All stores with the given product

```
user.stores.joins(:products).where("products.id = ?", 1234)
```

Comment: In my case is special,User has_many stores and Store belongs_to User though

Comment: The answer still remains the same. I have updated the models based on your comment. Take a look.

Comment: Thanks.But still based on my action i cant access product_id,it cant find it.

Comment: That is why i was thinking if there is any other way using scope options or something like that ,that way i dont have to go through trying to find ids.

Comment: I think your model is correct, but she indicates (possibly incorrectly) that Store belongs_to Product (if `current_user.stores.where(:product_id => 1)` returns results). @katie, I think the question should be how to get the product id you want; Rails can't infer which products you're looking to scope by. Well, you *could* create a scope and hard-code the product id, but that is *not* what you should do.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Search for stores with certain products? How are you (I mean you personally) identifying which stores or products you want people to see? Like "active" products or something? I think there's an unmentioned concept here.

Comment: @woahdae Thanks for the tip.I want to list stores a user own but per certain product

Comment: Could you give an example of the criteria you use to determine the product?

Comment: Does not look like a model issue to me. Why don't you try to execute the commands on Rails console and see if it works.